# How are abstract relations represented neurally?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, cognitive-neuroscience, fmri

It is known that concepts with similar attributes (color, shape... Etc.) are represented in a similar manner in the brain. However, is there any evidence of abstract relations, such as the as causal relation between two events are also represented in similar manners?

For a example, the relation between a switch and a light (wherein the tilting of the switch causes the light to turn on), should have the same representation as a knob and a light (wherein the turning of the knob causes the light to turn on).

What experimental setup could be used to test this with fMRI?

Comment: I have been informed that experiments are currently being run investigating this. I'll answer this question once the results are published.

Comment: While you're at it, could you also elaborate a little more on the question? It is not entirely clear to me yet.

Comment: @RobinKramer is it better now?

Comment: Hi Seanny, is there any update on the research? I'm rather interested now :)

Comment: @RobinKramer unfortunately none that I know of... This might remain unanswered for some time.

Comment: @RobinKramer New relevant paper on [metaphor production networks in the brain](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28038366) which is related this [review](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3951481/).

Comment: I think the _title_ question is too broad and will require decades of further research to answer because if you ask _how_ abstract relations are _represented_ neurally I would say we have almost no clue. I would also argue that we don't _how_ color or shape are represented. We mostly only know roughly _where_ things are represented by correlations with BOLD activity. So I'd suggest to formulate it more specifically, maybe: Do abstract relations show similar brain activity as measured by fmri ?

Comment: @robinkramer new paper showing succeasor representation between objects https://elifesciences.org/content/6/e17086